Azure Function App: Deploy zip with code + executable via Azure Portal
I have a zip file with a Python script and a Linux executable (used by the script). I wish to deploy this to my Azure Function using the Azure Portal GUI (not github, VS or the commandline).
In the Azure Function / Deployment Center I only seem to be able to have the below options, however:

What I am looking for is the equivalent to AWS Lambda's ability to upload a zip file with the relevant code. Is that indeed not a possibility?
If so, is it alternatively possible to store my zip in my Azure Blob Storage container and then reference that container URL via my Azure Function instead?


Is that indeed not a possibility?

Correct.

If so, is it alternatively possible to store my zip in my Azure Blob Storage container and then reference that container URL via my Azure Function instead?

Yes, there are a number of examples in this repo. What you mention, reference file on blob storage for Linux Consumption plan is this one: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/function-app-arm-templates/blob/main/function-app-linux-consumption/README.md
